# Carrierwave - Uniqueness of original_filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

When does Carrierwave save the model is mounted on?

Is it after uploading to AWS or before?

I would like to know because I'm saving the original_filename and making it Unique at my model, but this isnt ensuring uniqueness of the original_filename.

If two requests, with same filename, are sent at the sametime, I will get both records on my DB.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/rafaelcgo/87cf7a0651e40a02af9e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carrierwave stores the file [after](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb#L28) saving the record. Note that this is *before* committing the save, so it's still possible to rollback the save if something goes wrong during store.

Your problem may be in `validates_uniqueness_of`. It doesn't work across transactions. See [here](http://erniemiller.org/2013/05/22/talk-an-intervention-for-activerecord/) (19:16), and [here](http://izumi.plan99.net/blog/index.php/2008/09/20/validates_uniqueness_of-does-not-guarantee-uniqueness/).

Comment: that is exactly what I was thinking... I'll check the workarounds to try to fix it.